# How to get accuracy Pyplot image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to get accuracy image using python. And I using this example link below
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/create-image-classification-model-python-keras/
I got some error, any one please help me.[This is my project stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bugBN.png)

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyY5i.png)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), include_top = False, weights = "imagenet")

base_model.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([base_model,
                                 tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                                 tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
                                 tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")                                     
                                ])

base_learning_rate = 0.00001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs = 500 , validation_data = (x_val, y_val))
acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
epochs_range = range(500)

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The error is explicit, the variable `x_train` does not exist. You are about to train your model with no data the compiler complain about it.

Comment: Project Structure have two folder (train and valid) inside data folder. train and valid have 1000 images.

Comment: Your program will not find this data magically. You need to load it, split train and validation and then bind it to your function call. Variable does not exist this is the error you have... Just trying to help here.

Comment: On the link you provided: step 2, loading the data. This step is totally missing in your approach.